# Javascript function not giving expected results for image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, function

This code when run should resize the height and width that a image to fit the container.

This is the output from the code(from alerts):

2488: Images natural height

3264: Images natural width

450: The containers height

1063: The containers width

612: New height

844: New width

4: The number of times it was divided to get to output

**It should divide it 6 times to provide the outcome of:

New width: 544

New height: 414
**

I am almost certain that the problem is in the Java Script:

```js
function resize(iid, eid) {
//Get the ID of the elements (ele being the container that the image is in and img being the image its self)
     var img = document.getElementById('img');
     var ele = document.getElementById('contaner');
//makes the var needed
     var currentwidth = ele.clientWidth;
     var currentheight = ele.clientHeight;
     var naturalheight = img.naturalHeight;
     var naturalwidth = img.naturalWidth;
     var newheight = naturalheight;
     var newwidth = naturalwidth;
     var x = 0;
     //runs a loop that should size the image
        while (newheight > currentheight && newwidth > currentwidth){
            x = x + 1;
            newheight = naturalheight / x;
            newwidth = naturalwidth / x;
        }
     newheight = Math.ceil(newheight);
     newwidth = Math.ceil(newwidth);
     //alerts out the  answers
     alert(naturalheight);
     alert(naturalwidth);
     alert(currentheight);
     alert(currentwidth);
     alert(newheight);
     alert(newwidth);
     alert(x);
}
```

```css
#contaner {
    height: 450px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    position: relative;
}

#img {
    height: 450px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="contaner">
                <img src = "..\..\Resorces\Images\SlideShow\img1.jpg" style="width:652px;height:489px;" id="img"/>
                <div id="left_holder"><img onClick="slide(-1)" src="..\..\Resorces\Images\arrow_left.png" class="left"/></div>
                <div id="right_holder"><img onClick="slide(+1)" src="..\..\Resorces\Images\arrow_right.png" class="right"/></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
while (newheight > currentheight && newwidth > currentwidth)
```

It's stopping as soon as *either* width or height fits within the container, where as it seems like you want *both* to fit within the bounds of the container. Change to `||` and you'll get six iterations:

```
while (newheight > currentheight || newwidth > currentwidth)
```